# Global names start behaving like local

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a code with two functions calling themselves after a fixed period of time. I'm using `threading` to achieve this. Here is my code:

```
import threading

fun1_flag = True
fun2_flag = True

def fun1():
        threading.Timer(10,fun1).start()
        print("Entered Fun1")
        fun1_flag = True

def fun2():
        threading.Timer(30,fun2).start()
        print("Entered Fun2")
        fun2_flag = True

fun1()
fun2()

while True:
    if fun1_flag == True:
        print("Fun1 executed")
        fun1_flag = False
    if fun2_flag == True:
        print("Fun2 executed")
        fun2_flag = False
```

When I executed the above code, I got the following result:

```
Entered Fun1
Entered Fun2
Fun1 executed
Fun2 executed
Entered Fun1
Entered Fun1
Entered Fun2
Entered Fun1
Entered Fun1
Entered Fun1
Entered Fun2
```

I was wondering that I've declared the `fun1_flag` and `fun2_flag` as global names, still they are not changing their state when called by functions. 
I made them global inside the function and wrote like this:

```
def fun1():
        global fun1_flag
        threading.Timer(10,fun1).start()
        print("Entered Fun1")
        fun1_flag = True

def fun2():
        global fun2_flag
        threading.Timer(30,fun2).start()
        print("Entered Fun2")
        fun2_flag = True
```

Now the code was working fine as per my expectation. But then, When I tried to Interrupt the output using `ctrl+C`, it started behaving like previous code. The state of names stopped to change again. The output of the code was like this:

```
Entered Fun1
Entered Fun2
Fun1 executed
Fun2 executed
Entered Fun1
Fun1 executed
Entered Fun1
Fun1 executed
Entered Fun2Entered Fun1

Fun2 executed
Fun1 executed
Entered Fun1
Fun1 executed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\theas\Desktop\thread_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    if fun2_flag == True:
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> Entered Fun1
Entered Fun2
Entered Fun1
Entered Fun1
Entered Fun1
Entered Fun2
Entered Fun1
Entered Fun1
```

I'm not able to understand this behavior of name declaration. I'll use this code in raspberry Pi in future. I tried to execute it there but still the result was same. Please help me to solve this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Here in the code, I'm sending some data using `requests.post()` in the `if` condition in `while`. I'm expecting the data to be transmitted after every 30 seconds but I'm getting only once. 
I've put this code in startup files of my OS. It runs on startup, while loop is running continuously, the functions are being executed on their expected time. But names `fun1_flag` and `fun2_flag` are not updating even after declaring them as global. That's my problem.

Comment: In your first code you simply created 2 local variables `fun1_flag` and `fun2_flag` to the respective function. So the functions always print and your main loop prints once (because it looks on the outer scope variables which are assigned to False). Regarding the ctrl+C, you simply killed the main thread but not the child ones. You might want to make them [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon)s

Comment: When the names are global already, any function can't change their state?

Comment: Yes they can, as you did in your second piece of code. If you don't declare it `global` inside the function, Python will simply create a new local variable...

Comment: But even after declaring them global, They are creating the same problem as I stated in the last. I put this code in startup. It gets executed only once. I'm not able to move further.

Comment: No you showed that when you added the `global` it worked fine until you interrupted the program with ctrl+c. And then, I also explained to you what is the problem

Comment: Yeah, but while implementing the code in real scenario(startup of the OS), it works only for once. In the while loop, data is being transmitted over the ```https``` inside the if condition on the place of ```print("Fun1 executed")```. I expect the data after every 30 seconds, but I get it once.

Comment: Sorry there was nothing about https or computer startup in the question. Apparently this is relevant information so try to edit your question to be more specific and clear